# How to copy file from Salt-Minion [Windows] to Salt-Master. "cp.push module not working"

Tags: salt-stack, cac, salt-cloud

I'm trying to copy file from Salt-Minion [**Windows**] to Salt-Master using cp.push module. Although it's works fine in Linux Minion's. The only problem I'm facing for Windows Minion's. Its returning false. Is there any other way to perform this task please let know. It would be very helpful to me.

## Salt-Master

- Version: 3002.2
- OS: RHEL7

## Salt-Minion

- Version: 3002.2
- OS: Windows Server 2016

Comment: I have exact same issue, did you find a solution?